# How do I compare data in same column in same table

Tags: mysql

I need to compare the data between 2017 and 2016 in same column in the same table.

For now I use 2 queries:

1st query :

```
  SELECT 
      SUM(a.netamt) AS netamt2017, b.store_name, c.budget
  FROM 
      site_sales a 
  JOIN 
      site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
  JOIN 
      site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
  WHERE 
      c.busidate = '2017-01' 
      AND a.busidate >= '2017-01-01' 
      AND a.busidate <= '2017-01-15'
  GROUP BY 
      a.storenum
```

This for find netamt 2017

2nd query:

```
  SELECT 
      SUM(a.netamt) AS netamt2016, b.store_name, c.budget
  FROM 
      site_sales a 
  JOIN 
      site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
  JOIN  
      site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
  WHERE 
      c.busidate = '2017-01' 
      AND a.busidate >= '2016-01-01' 
      AND a.busidate <= '2016-01-15'
  GROUP BY 
      a.storenum
```

This for finding "Netamt 2016".

I need to combine these 2 queries to form this table:

[Here is example for the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i94TO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `sum(case when ... then ... else ... end)` syntax:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-15' THEN a.netamt ELSE 0 END) as netamt2016,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-15' THEN a.netamt ELSE 0 END) as netamt2017,
    b.store_name,
    c.budget
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
JOIN site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
WHERE c.busidate = '2017-01'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

***Note:*** Cause you used `GROUP BY`, and `b.store_name`, `c.budget` did not be aggregated, so these two columns are meanless.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for the answer. it works great ! :)